# Scan C disk and copy files

Tags: powershell, copy, backup, restore

I would appreciate some help here.

1. The Powershell script should close Outlook process which works.
2. Aswell as scan C disk for .pst files which works.
3. Copy these files to "\fileserver01\temp\test\"
4. Export to csv/excel list where these files where located and last write time.
5. Possible hide error messages for the user when running the script since it complains about not full access on a few folders when running the scan.

Code:

```
Get-Process outlook | Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() }

Get-ChildItem -path c:\ -recurse -include *.pst | `
Copy-Item -destination "\\fileserver01\temp\test\" | `
Select-object fullname,lastwritetime|export-csv "\\fileserver01\temp\test\"
```

How should I fix the last couple of things on my list?
Thanks

Comment: For 1. on your list you can use `Stop-Process -Name Outlook*`

Comment: Don't forget to mark the right answer as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to use double backslash for UNC paths.
Second, the copy-item does not output anything to the pipeline, you have to use the -Passthru parameter.

```
Get-ChildItem -path z:\ -recurse -include *.pst  -PipelineVariable source | 
    Copy-Item -Destination "\\path\temp" -Verbose -PassThru | 
    Select-Object @{n="Source";e={$source.versioninfo.filename}},fullname,lastwritetime | export-csv "\\path\temp\copy_result.csv" -Append -Verbose
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up with this. I still got 1 thing left which is a bit strange. In the csv/excel file it says that fullname is the destination location. I would like the source to be typed instead. The lastwritetime is correct though.

Comment: I updated my example to use the pipelinevariable. Now it outputs the source, destination (fullname) and lastwritetime in the .csv.

Comment: Thank you. However it doesn't seem to work. I am coding in Powershell 2.0

Comment: Oh, in that case ... no idea. I made it against version 4.0. The only things that changed is the pipelinevariable and the use of the scriptblocks in the Select-Object. The only other option is to put every step in another variable and iterate over that, or drop the source requirement in the .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that after the files are copied, the object is gone from the pipeline.

This works:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Include *.pst -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime | Export-Csv -Path "\fileserver01\temp\test\MyCSV.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer the question you've asked, as @Adamar's answer appears to do just that.

however, your issue could also be resolved by querying ost/pst files from registry using a snippet like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Search).Property | ? {$_ -match "(o|p)st$"}
```

which will return all of the ost/pst files the logged in user has open in outlook.

a snippet like this will then copy them all to a network share and print the logs to a file.

```
$FilesToCopy = (Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Search).Property | ? {$_ -match "(o|p)st$"}
$FilesToCopy | ForEach { Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination "\\network\share" ; $_ | Out-File "\\network\share\log.txt" -Append }
```

This saves a LOT of time over indexing through all of the `C:` drive - there's also an issue where very long directory names (greater than 260 char length) are not indexed properly by `Get-ChildItem` - making this method a bit more reliable and appealing for a production script.

Comment: Does this also work for ost/pst that are not imported in outlook? Can't check myself since indexing is completely disabled at work (VDI).

Comment: Thank you Connor. I will keep this in mind if I notice it takes alot of time. I am new to this forum and I am really happy for your guys support.

Comment: @Adamar this only lists PST's that are in any outlook profile as far as I know, you'd need to do a full FS index to find others.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code.
Thanks everyone for your support.

```
#Kill Oulook process
Get-Process outlook -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |   Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() } 

#Scan for .pst files on the C disk
Get-ChildItem -path c:\ -recurse -include *.pst -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |

#Copy located .pst files to the destination
Copy-Item -Destination "\\networkpath\home\$env:username\ComputerChange\" -Verbose -PassThru -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 

#Log where files were located and when they were last written to.
Select-Object fullname,lastwritetime | export-csv \\networkpath\home\$env:username\ComputerChange\PSTlog.csv -Verbose


Write-Host "PST Files have successfully been copied, press any key to close" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have created a much faster script as I have excluded some systemfolders and programfiles folders where .PST files doesn't save.
I bet some of you expert can find out why this code doesn't work?

```
#Exclude systemfolders etc
$folders=get-childitem c:\ | where-object{$_.mode -like "d-*" -AND $_.name -notlike "windows" -AND $_.name -notlike "drivers" -AND $_.name -notlike "program files*"}

#Search thru each root folder for PST-files
$allfiles=$folders | ForEach-Object{get-childitem -Path $_.fullname -include "*.pst" -recurse -ErrorAction silentlycontinue};

$env:username
$foldertocreate="\\destination\$env:username\"

#Check if folder with username exists in the \\destination folder otherwise create folder with username.       
if((Test-Path -Path $foldertocreate -PathType Container)) {write-host "Folder already created"}

        else {write-host "Creating Folder", New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $foldertocreate }                              

#Copy .PST files which is in $allfiles to the folder created in fileshare> $foldertocreate.

#Copy .PST files in $allfiles to the destination folder created.
robocopy $allfiles $foldertocreate

Write-Host "Press any key to close" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") 
end
```